# QT to Python converted code different to each other

Tags: matplotlib, qt4, python-3.6

To begin with i was refering [this](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/sample_chapters/7900-matplotlib-for-python-developers-sample-chapter-6-embedding-matplotlib-in-qt-4.pdf) book to embed my Matplotlib chart in to QT Designer, i designed my GUI as show in the book but when converted the XML to Python both codes differ to eachother mainly the main classes and imports. Check codes below,

**My Converted Code**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MplMainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MplMainWindow):
        MplMainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MplMainWindow"))
        MplMainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.mplcentralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MplMainWindow)
        self.mplcentralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mplcentralwidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.mplcentralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.mplhorizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.mplhorizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mplhorizontalLayout"))
        self.mpllineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.mplcentralwidget)
        self.mpllineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mpllineEdit"))
        self.mplhorizontalLayout.addWidget(self.mpllineEdit)
        self.mplpushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.mplcentralwidget)
        self.mplpushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mplpushButton"))
```

**The code as seen in the book** (Screen shots taken from the book)

[image]

As seen in both codes my code doesn't have any such imports which are displayed in the book and the class name along with the parameters are completely different. 
This may be a basic question but i could not find out the answer. Clarification on this matter will help me to understand the problems i have regarding this section. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know the book at all, but there seems to be a misconception. Those lines shown in the book need to be typed in by yourself. QT designer creates the GUI, but it does not import matplotlib canvas or even create your plot for you.

Comment: Yes i may have misunderstood. So even the import FigureCanvasQTAgg should be manually typed? Won't it be auto generated in the conversion after "drag and drop" all the components in the widget?

Comment: Yes, the complete content of what the book calls `mplwidget.py`. According to that book chapter QT designer will create the file `qtdesigner.py`. Then you have to create the `mplwidget.py` yourself. Everything that has to do with matplotlib is not autogenerated in the example from the book.

Comment: Oh! thank you for helping me out :)